# If $\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X_i)=0$, the $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ can take values of $X_1,X_2\cdots$. Now suppose $E(Y\mid X=X_i)=0$ holds for every $X_i$, does it mean that $X$ and $Y$ are not correlated?

Intuitively I think this is true, since no matter what value $X$ takes, the expectation of $Y$ is unchanged, therefore the two must be uncorrelated. However I don't know how to prove this mathematically.

Comment: Try to evaluate $E(XY)$, and do it like this - $E(XY) = E(E(XY|X))$. Its obviously 0. Then Writing $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$, is remains to show that $E(X)E(Y) =0$, which is also so. Just again take $E(Y) = E(E(Y|X))$. (I supposed that you know $E(E(Z|U)) = E(Z)$, for any $U$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(XY)=E_X[\sum_{i≥1 } E(X_i Y| X=X_i)]=E_X[0] =0$
Similarly $E(Y)=0$ Thus we have $Cov(X,Y)=0$

Comment: I think you mean $E[XY] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[XY|X=X_i]P[X=X_i]$ (which is the law of total expectation, assuming $X \in \{X_1, X_2, ...\}$).   The notation $E_X[\cdot]$ that you use does not quite make sense.  You could alternatively say $E[XY] = E_X[E[XY|X]]$.

Comment: Yes in ur notation $ E[XY]=E_X [E[XY|X]]  $ and then u evaluate the inner expectation to get what I wrote directly

Comment: No, the inner expectation $E[XY|X]$ is a function of $X$, i.e., it is a random variable that can be written as $g(X)$, it is certainly not $\sum_{i \geq 1} E[X_iY|X=X_i]$, which is not a function of $X$ and is not even random.

Comment: I guess my notation is a bit sloppy but this is what I mean

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|X)) =  \mathbb{E}(0) = 0$

$\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(XY|X)) = \mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{E}(Y|X)) = \mathbb{E}(X \times 0) = 0$

Therefore, $\mathbb{C}(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y) = 0$.